# ADAM Administration from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, adam

We're in the process of building a MOSS site and one of the 3rd party tools we're using has a requirement of AD/ADAM as the authentication provider.  We would like the user's to manage their own accounts (e.g. resetting passwords, registering new users, etc) so we're going to need WebParts for administering users in an AD/ADAM/LDAP DB.

Are there any SharePoint WebParts out there already to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across one today called [AD User Editor](http://nominesptools.codeplex.com/). It states you can edit nearly any Active Directory property, and it works in multi-domain environments.

From the UI screenshot it appears to use a web part and take on the SharePoint look and feel.

Even better it's on CodePlex so any problems you can fix yourself!